# unittest.main() crashes python interpreter in Spyder

Tags: python, spyder, python-unittest

I have a python script containing a `unittest.TestCase`, with a `setUp()` function and a small number of `test_foo_does_bar()`-type functions.

The script ends as follows:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

When I run this script in Spyder (see below for config details) the interpreter stops at the following line:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran x tests in x.xxxs

FAILED (failures=x)
```

No amount of Ctrl+C or Ctrl+D can rescue the interpreter and get me back to the prompt. The same script, run from the command prompt, terminates as normal.

Is this a bug in Spyder or am I missing something?

*Setup info:*
Spyder 2.2.3
Python 2.7.5 64bits. Qt 4.8.4, PyQt4 (API v2) 4.9.6 on Windows

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't crash the Python interpreter, it terminates it. This is normal behavior for the script.
You can see it yourself: in `main.py` it is stated, `main = TestProgram`; this means that `unittest.main()` will call the `TestProgram` class, which in its `__init__(self)` calls `self.runTests()`,  which ends with this:

```
if self.exit:
    sys.exit(not self.result.wasSuccessful())
```

So it has a specific call to `sys.exit()`, which terminates the interpreter.

In fact, if you run it as command line, you return to the command line; and if you start command-line Python, import the module and call the function, you will see that you'll return to the command prompt - you don't stay in Python.

If you want the script to NOT terminate the interpreter, just state it when calling the funcion:

```
unittest.main(exit=False)
```